# tty cuts right side but still types word

Tags: terminal, tty

So my Dragonboard embedded board, running the latest version of Linaro, is hooked up to a screen via HDMI (no ssh or anything) and I disabled xserver/window managers so I just have the tty screen.

It "cuts off" the right part (20 characters in screenshot) of the screen when I type, but it is typing as if I keep typing it wraps around as it should on the next line. I thought my screen was dead, but opening up x-server and chromium I **can verify** the screen isn't broken. Text editors (vim, emacs, etc) get cut off as well. This just suddenly happened and another board with fresh Linaro works on screen.

Tried `reset` (just flashes screen and don't fix it) and my `checkwinsize` is on (set it with shotp). also, it is also the same across all tty's

Even a solution for forcing it to wrap after the first part is great, I just can't edit any text reasonably now

[image]

Comment: Can you describe this more clearly (and/or provide screenshot(s) and/or photograph(s))? It sounds like you’re saying that the right edge of the window is off-screen. Can you move the window back to the left?  P.S. What operating system?  What windowing software?  What terminal program?  What editor?  Do you have any similar behavior with other windows?

Comment: What's a "tty screen"? Do you mean a virtual console? A terminal emulator's window?

Comment: @AlexP I have an HDMI cable hooked up a dragonboard (like a raspberry pi) and turned off xserver so its just the tty terminal console, but all on board, nothing virtual or remoting in

Comment: @G-Man Updated description, but there is no window managers and its just a bash terminal in tty screen

Comment: [Virtual console](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console). The only thing that comes to my mind is that there is a mismatch between what Linux and the monitor believe to be the video mode. Maybe try changing the video mode?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  So “cuts off” seems to be misleading; the screen is there, but characters don’t display.  Specifically, the screen is 100 characters wide, and only the first 80 are visible.  80 characters wide is the historic standard window size; I presume that you’re dealing with *something* that thinks your screen is 80 characters wide. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  So when you say “text editor”, do you just mean something like `vi`, `nano` or `emacs` *running in that same window where you are have the problem with the shell?*  Can you clarify: is this a screen that’s being driven directly by your embedded board, or is it something like an ssh connection?  Do `reset` and `checkwinsize` give any response?  What does ``stty size`` say?  Does ``stty columns 100`` do anything?

Comment: Your question might have been clearer and more readily understood from the beginning if you had used the word ‘‘monitor’’ instead of ‘‘screen’’.

Answer (score 2):

To answer my own issue (thanks to G-Man and AlexP for helping), it was simply my HDMI cable is slightly bad, and wiggling it around fixed the problem.

This makes sense too since it was a "physical" display that was the issue